# Do bounties attract upvotes, or is this just a coincidence?

Tags: discussion, bounty, upvotes

I just had an old question which I thought was useful. It had 0 votes, and it had some attention from before. But now I started a **bounty**, and I got 2 upvotes in 30 seconds. That's a lot. **Plus** I've honestly **never** seen a heavily downvoted question that had a bounty, even when it was bad. Does this mean that people feel grateful for the bounty and give an upvote? Is it just merely a coincidence, or am I wrong? Is this **bad upvoting**? I know a user is free to upvote whatever he wants, but I'm just asking if people actually think this way.

Comment: More eyes on the question = possibility of more upvotes (ideally based solely on the merit of the question). I doubt anyone upvotes merely because you offered a bounty.

Comment: @rene that version also included questions with no bounties at all - [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/516393/653260/) is a new version.

Comment: I was wondering why I blew up SEDE with that query @Glorfindel.  Thanks ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bounty tends to draw more attention to a question. This usually means more people will see the question, and possibly vote on it. So yes, bounties do attract upvotes, but they can also attract downvotes.

> I've honestly NEVER seen a heavily downvoted question that had a bounty, even when it was bad.

I have. It's not very common, but sometimes an off-topic question is not closed in the first 2 days, and the OP places a bounty on it. Once a bounty is placed, it can only be closed if a moderator removes the bounty (which can happen before the bounty lasts too long, so it may not get to the first page). People will still vote on it though, even if they can't close it.

I've also seen some other sketchy cases where the bounty system was abused and the questions involved subsequently attracted downvotes.

Answer (score 8):

#### TL;DR

Yes, bounties do attract upvotes (±2 on average), but they do not attract downvotes.

---

#### Full answer

I constructed a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/516393/653268/) for all question bounties posted in the first half of 2016. During the bounty period (7 days), they received an average number of **3.35 upvotes** and **0.18 downvotes**. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37205465) had the worst fate; while bountied, it received 0 upvotes and 8 downvotes. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36827659/compiling-an-application-for-use-in-highly-radioactive-environments) received 8 downvotes during the bounty as well, but compensated it with a whopping 847 upvotes.

In another [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/516463/653359/#resultSets), I collected the number of up- and downvotes on *all* questions posted in that period, counting the votes from day 3 to day 10. This resulted in an average of **1.56** upvotes and **0.18** downvotes.

For reference, here are the complete queries:

```sql
create table #posts (postid int, bountydate datetime, upvotes int, downvotes int);

insert into #posts
select p.id, bv.creationdate,
  sum(case uv.votetypeid when 2 then 1 else 0 end) as upvotes,
  sum(case uv.votetypeid when 3 then 1 else 0 end) as downvotes
  from posts as p
  inner join votes as bv
    on bv.postid = p.id
  left outer join votes as uv
    on uv.postid = bv.postid
    and uv.creationdate >= bv.creationdate
    and uv.creationdate < dateadd(day, 7, bv.creationdate)
  where bv.votetypeid = 8
    and p.posttypeid = 1
    and uv.votetypeid in (2, 3)
    and bv.creationdate between '2016-01-01' and '2016-07-01'
  group by p.id, bv.creationdate
  order by upvotes, downvotes desc;
  
select top 100 postid as [Post Link], bountydate as 'Bounty date',
  upvotes as 'Number of upvotes',
  downvotes as 'Number of downvotes'
  from #posts
  order by upvotes, downvotes desc;

select avg(cast (upvotes as float)) as 'Average number of upvotes',
       avg(cast (downvotes as float)) as 'Average number of downvotes'
  from #posts
```

---

```sql
create table #posts (postid int, upvotes int, downvotes int);

insert into #posts
select p.id,
  sum(case uv.votetypeid when 2 then 1 else 0 end) as upvotes,
  sum(case uv.votetypeid when 3 then 1 else 0 end) as downvotes
  from posts as p
  left outer join votes as uv
    on uv.postid = p.id
    and uv.creationdate >= dateadd(day, 3, p.creationdate)
    and uv.creationdate < dateadd(day, 10, p.creationdate)
  where p.posttypeid = 1
    and uv.votetypeid in (2, 3)
    and p.creationdate between '2016-01-01' and '2016-07-01'
  group by p.id
  order by upvotes, downvotes desc;
  
select top 100 postid as [Post Link],
  upvotes as 'Number of upvotes',
  downvotes as 'Number of downvotes'
  from #posts
  order by upvotes desc, downvotes desc;

select avg(cast (upvotes as float)) as 'Average number of upvotes',
       avg(cast (downvotes as float)) as 'Average number of downvotes'
  from #posts
```