# Does placing a bounty affect reputation gained?

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounty

As in, do you still gain reputation for upvotes on the question you placed the bounty on, while the bounty is in affect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, placing a bounty has no effect on that. On smaller sites in the Stack Exchange network, a bounty can refund itself in this way; on Stack Overflow, that's [less likely](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/329199/4751173).